# How to build an iOS like settings module?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, inappsettingskit

I am really new to iPhone development. Currentlly I am setting up an option module for my application. The user should be able to edit some preferences.

My first approach was to have some text fields. But I really like how iOS handles editing preferences. There is some kind of label.  Clicking on that label opens another view with a field for editing. I hope you understand what I mean.

How does iOS achieve this? Is that table view?

I mean this kind of design

[image]

Comment: As seen in your screenshot (bottom text says it), try InAppSettingsKit. ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

InAppSettingsKit as already recommended by @hennes is used for extending functionality that is already available.

If you add a Settings.bundle to your app then if it is correctly installed it will automatically show up in the Settings.app provided by Apple.

Comment: hm what I actually mean is to have this kind of settings straight in my app and not in the iPhone settings

Comment: That's what InAppSettingsKit does. It provides an interface in your app to the global settings setup using Settings.bundle.

Comment: Don't think any of this is relevant anymore since InAppSettingsKit doesn't look to have updated for iOS7.

Comment: Either the link is broken or you'r good at deciphering asian characters.. I can't make anything sensible out of it :-)

Comment: As I said almost a year ago, this is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 6):

IF you want it just in your app, just use a tableView set to Group style.  There are a lot of tutorials on TableViews

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/).

Answer (score 3):

There is another option, you can use BaseKit (I'm the author)

Source repo https://github.com/brunow/BaseKit
Example of settings http://blog.brunowernimont.be/2012/06/22/example_of_settings_controller_with_basekit.html

Comment: the blog link is broken.