# Creating a settings view for app ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to create a settings view within my app that so many apps today have implemented. In the past, I have created a settings bundle which the users can modify there settings for my app by going into system settings.

My question is can I implement the .plist settings from the settings bundle into an ordinary view within my app? And if so, how is this done?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338390/how-to-build-an-ios-like-settings-module

Comment: The answer provided in the linked question is to use [`InAppSettingsKit`](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/).

Comment: InAppSettingsKit is lots of overhead if you just want to store a few user settings though.  Best thing is to find out what the poster needs.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.inappsettingskit.com/ does what you want. The example that comes with the source code will be great resources to look at.

Answer (score 4):

The two major options you got are:

1. Create a PList within your project and assign key/value pairs and then create a ViewController that includes UISwitches, TextBoxes, Sliders, etc and then just use these controls to integrate with that PList.
2. If you are talking less than 4-5 settings, use NSUserDefaults to store/read the values of these settings.  You will still need to create a ViewController for the UI, but won't need a PList.

I personally like having settings within the app for most cases.  Legal statements, copyright notices and settings that won't be touched but once are probably better off using the SettingsBundle, but for settings that are updated or changed often should reside inside the app in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess NSUserDefaults would be gr8 option if you not saving large amount of data.